# react native app release hangs forever at app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

after upgrading my react-native app to version 0.60.5, the application works just fine in debugging mode but when i try to get the android release files of my app by running this command:

```
react-native run-android --variant=release
```

the progress gets stuck at this line:

```
> :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease
```

and hangs on forever

note: i tried to delete the build and gradle folders and run `./gradlew clean` but didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

The command you want to use is a command to test `APK`, and you need to set it up to sign the app before that.

> `Note:` that --variant=release is only available if you've set up
>   signing as described above.

See this [official document](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android) to create a release app for signature and upload keys.

Comment: i even tried to run  `cd android  && ./gradlew bundleRelease` as the documentation said, it didn't work either.

Comment: @Mohammadaltenji Have you carried out all those before steps?